# Choices in Django forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am editing the code below to fit `forms`. What would be the most convenient replacement for `choices` (below) in a way that they would function similarly to their use in `models`?

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=30)
    USER_LEVEL = (
            ('admin', 'Admin'),
            ('staff', 'Staff'),
            ('hof', 'Head of Facilities'),
            ('user', 'User'),
        )
    user_level = forms.CharField(max_length=7, choices=USER_LEVEL, default='user')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a [`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield).

```
user_level = forms.ChoiceField(max_length=7, choices=USER_LEVEL, default='user')
```